# ChromeDriver Version 121+ Forces "Save As" Dialog - How to Bypass? (Selenium/Java)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Have been working on automating file downloads using Selenium WebDriver with ChromeDriver in Java.

My code was working perfectly until I updated to ChromeDriver version 121+, the code worked fine till Chrome 119, problem seems to start in Chrome `121.0.6167.140`. Now, it seems that the browser is forcing the "Save As" dialog box to appear, even when I have set Chrome preferences to avoid it.

Also I want to execute test cases in incognito mode only

This is also not working.

```
options.addArguments("disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");
```

Comment: Can you share the complete list of capabilities that you're adding to your test?

Comment: Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
          prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1); 
          prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1);
          prefs.put("download.default_directory", defaultDownloadPath);
          prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
          List<String> enabledLabsExperiments = new ArrayList<>();
          enabledLabsExperiments.add("download-bubble@2");
          enabledLabsExperiments.add("download-bubble-v2@2");

Comment: prefs.put("browser.enabled_labs_experiments", enabledLabsExperiments);
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
          options.setExperimentalOption("localState", prefs);
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");// To remove warning info message in chrome.
          options.addArguments("--incognito");
          options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
          options.addArguments("disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");

Answer (score 0):

The arguments that needs to be added to the capabilities to disable the download popup is `options.addArguments("--disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");` instead of `options.addArguments("disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");`

Additionally, sharing the capabilities that I use for enabling Chrome to download files (in Java):

```java
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();

prefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.dir"));
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments(
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--remote-allow-origins=*",
    "--disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2",
    "--disable-popup-blocking"
);
```

Comment: this is not working problem is i have just extra arguments for incognito mode
options.addArguments("--incognito");
if i remove it then it is working but in mycase i want testcase to run in incognito mode only

Comment: That solution is not working when "--incognito" option is present.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run in headless mode and it allowed me to download the file

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

OR This worked in my side.

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(args); // Use your args
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); // Use your prefs

ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("behavior", "allow");
params.put("downloadPath", "//yourDownloadPath");
commandParams.put("params", params);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);
String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + driver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
httpClient.execute(request);
```